# Do I need commas on both sides of "в частности"?

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need commas on both sides of "в частности"? For example:

> Во всех малых городах России, **в частности**, в Челябинске и Пензе,
> можно обнаружить эти виды голубей.
>
> Хотя он и слыл отличником, по некоторым предметам, **в частности**, по
> математике и химии, он уже начинал заметно сдавать.
>
> Революции только за редким исключением, **в частности** в Европе, не
> приводили к пролитию крови и потерям жизней.
>
> Программирование, **в частности** на таких языках как C++ и
> AutoHotKey, быстро стало его главным занятием в свободное время.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю сам себе:

1. Если Пенза и Челябинск входят в понятие "малые города России", то запятая сразу после "в частности" не нужна.
2. Если математика и химия входят в понятие "некоторые предметы", то запятая сразу после "в частности" не нужна.
3. Если Европа входит в понятие "редкие исключения", то запятая сразу после "в частности" не нужна.
4. Если помимо языков C++ и AutoHotKey он также программировал и на хотя бы ещё одном другом языке, что также составляло его главное занятие, то запятая сразу после "в частности" не нужна.

Так, во всех этих случаях, получается [уточняющий оборот](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/v-chastnosti-vydelyaetsya-zapyatymi.html), в котором слова "в частности" являются только лишь его началом. Поэтому запятыми выделяется весь оборот.